# How to set the rootView of a NSHostingController on a IBSegueAction?

Tags: swiftui

I have the code below where I'm trying to set the rootView of SettingsHostingController to SettingsView during an @IBSegueAction of my view controller. When I run this code I get:

`Method cannot be marked @IBSegueAction because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C`

I'm not sure how to fix that. Any ideas?

```swift
import AppKit
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
}

class SettingsHostingController: NSHostingController<SettingsView> {
    
}

class SettingsViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBSegueAction func openSettings(_ coder: NSCoder) -> SettingsHostingController? {
        let rootView = SettingsView()
        return SettingsHostingController(coder: coder, rootView: rootView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you can return it as base class type

```
class SettingsViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBSegueAction func openSettings(_ coder: NSCoder) -> NSViewController? {
        let rootView = SettingsView()
        return SettingsHostingController(coder: coder, rootView: rootView)
    }
}
```